do different Vaishnavite sects believe in a hierarchy among different forms of Vishnu?
For example, ISKCON seems to say that Vishnu is a "demigod".
https://vedabase.io/en/library/tlk/3/

When we speak of Viṣṇu, we mean Kṛṣṇa. Kṛṣṇa is the origin of the viṣṇu-tattva – that is, Viṣṇu is an expansion of Kṛṣṇa. When we speak of Viṣṇu, we understand that the origin of Viṣṇu is Kṛṣṇa. As Śrī Kṛṣṇa says in Bhagavad-gītā (10.2), aham ādir hi devānām: “I am the source of the demigods.”


The most important demigods (devas) are Brahmā, Śiva and Viṣṇu.


From madhva prespective all avataras are same (24 avataras as mentioned in srimad bhagavatam) expect privithi and balarama are avesha avataras)   only when avesha comes they will have fujll potency of vishnu, but parasurama is not avesha he is avatara only, where as sri vishanas budha and parasurama are not avatar or considered avesha of vishnu, in moksha no jiva can have the qualities of vishnu, because vishna and his qualities are not different for madhvas
